# htaccess 301 redirect from 5 folder to 1 folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to hatcchess 301 redirect thousand plus url, which are as follows:

domain.com/blog/2014/10/20/article-one/ to domain.com/article-one/

domain.com/blog/2014/10/20/article-two/ to domain.com/article-two/

domain.com/blog/2014/10/20/article-thousand/ to domain.com/article-thousand/

Hope you will answer with clear information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your **`/blog/.htaccess` file**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/(.+)$ /$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```

If `/blog/.htaccess` doesn't exist then you can use this code in your **`/DocumentRoot/.htaccess` file**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(blog)/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/(.+)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

This one code work great for me.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /blog/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /$4
```